# Python "show in finder"

Tags: python

How can I launch a new Finder window (or Explorer on Win) from python in a specific folder. The behaviour I'm looking for is the equivalent of "Show in finder" link in a tracks context menu in iTunes or most other programs come to think of it.

What I have currently is a UI built with PyQt and I'd like to add a menu option like "show log folder" or something similar, which would pop up a new finder window.

**UPDATE:**

From *katrielalex* advice trying `subprocess.Popen("/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app")` throws and `OSError: Permission denied`. Trying to launch the Finder.app by double clicking it says that it is in use by OS X and cannot be opened.

Surely there must be a way to open a new Finder window.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For OS X, you can use the Finder's Apple Events (AppleScript) interface via [py-appscript](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/):

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> file_to_show = "/Applications/iTunes.app"
>>> app("Finder").reveal(mactypes.Alias(file_to_show).alias)
app(u'/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app').startup_disk.folders[u'Applications'].application_files[u'iTunes.app']
>>> #  Finder window of "Applications" folder appears with iTunes selected
```

EDIT:

An even simpler solution on OS X 10.6 is to use the new `-R` (Reveal) option to the `open` command (see `man 1 open`):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> file_to_show = "/Applications/iTunes.app"
>>> subprocess.call(["open", "-R", file_to_show])
```

Comment: You can also shell out to e.g. `osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to reveal '/file/to/show'"` ... though getting the quote marks right can be tricky...

Answer (score 3):

```
from subprocess import call
targetDirectory = "~/Desktop"
call(["open", targetDirectory])
```

Comment: When I run as module, I get the error: call(["open", targetDirectory]))
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen( "explorer i:" )
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x00C46DB0>
```

Comment: I take it that `explorer` is the name of the process, what is `i:`

Comment: @Matti: the path to the folder. So if you wanted to open `c:\documents and settings\foo\bar` you would use `r"explorer 'c:\documents and settings\foo\bar'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a great library named `show-in-file-manager`. [[GitHub](https://github.com/damonlynch/showinfilemanager)]

So, with this simple task it goes like that:

```py
from showinfm import show_in_file_manager
show_in_file_manager("D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\logs")
```

Answer (score -1):

For Finder the shell command

```
open ~/
```

would open a new window.