# Python: Opening a folder in Explorer/Nautilus/Finder

Tags: python, cross-platform, directory

I'm in Python, and I have the path of a certain folder. I want to open it using the default folder explorer for that system. For example, if it's a Windows computer, I want to use Explorer, if it's Linux, I want to use Nautilus or whatever is the default there, if it's Mac, I want to use Finder.

How can I do that?

Comment: Seems to be 2/3 of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520493/python-show-in-finder

Answer (score 55):

I am surprised no one has mentioned using `xdg-open` for **nix* which will work for both files and folders:

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess

def open_file(path):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.startfile(path)
    elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
        subprocess.Popen(["open", path])
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", path])
```

Comment: How to select(highlight) a file while opening the folder in windows?

Comment: @mahemadhi: This should work: `subprocess.Popen(["explorer /select,", path])`

Comment: @Cas: it doesn't work. This does: `subprocess.Popen(["explorer", "/select,", path])`

Comment: @Ronan: it doesn't open the folder, it just select it

Comment: @AbdullahSaid: if you want to only open a folder and not select any files, use the actual answer (`os.startfile(path)`)

Answer (score 22):

You can use `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess
import sys

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    def openFolder(path):
        subprocess.check_call(['open', '--', path])
elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
    def openFolder(path):
        subprocess.check_call(['xdg-open', '--', path])
elif sys.platform == 'win32':
    def openFolder(path):
        subprocess.check_call(['explorer', path])
```

Comment: The OS X (`darwin`) code will attempt to open the file in its default application, not in a Finder window which seems to be what the OP wants.  As noted in another answer, you would need to do something different; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520493/python-show-in-finder .

Comment: @Ned: The question states, "I have the path of a certain folder".  I assumed, then, that file paths would not be passed to this function.  The same limitation applies to the Linux/Gnome code, which will also open files in their default applications.

Comment: Isn't `xdg-open` the more universal way to open given file in Linux?

Comment: I'd use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.check_call()`, since we don't usually want to wait those programs are finished (and the Windows version will actually err because of non-zero exit status).

Comment: @RonanPaixão: On OS X and Linux the processes will return correctly.  Are you sure that `explorer` will not return on Windows when called this way?  It works fine from the terminal.

Answer (score 16):

The following works on Macintosh.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file:///Users/test/test_folder')
```

On GNU/Linux, use the absolute path of the folder. (Make sure the folder exists)

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('/home/test/test_folder')
```

As pointed out in the other answer, it works on Windows, too.

Comment: I confirmed that it works on Windows! So simple and nice solution!

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Unlike the question would suggest, `webbrowser` opens the location in nautilus, explorer, finder or whatever, on any platform.

Comment: You can also add "file://" in front of it on linux and it still works. Just make sure that you use the absolute path and three slashes (`file:// /home/foo` = `file:///home/foo`).

Comment: this works in a plain python shell on ubuntu, but in another application (say in foundry's Nuke) it defaults to firefox

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have to detect the operating system, and then launch the relevant file explorer accordingly.

This could come in userful for OSX's Finder: [Python "show in finder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520493/python-show-in-finder)

*(The below only works for windows unfortunately)*

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.open('C:/path/to/folder')
```

This works on Windows. <strike>I assume it would work across other platforms. Can anyone confirm?</strike> Confirmed windows only :(

Comment: Does this work on Windows regardless of whether IE is the default browser?

Comment: Argh, you may have to detect the OS then :(

Comment: It gives me OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor on Linux.

Comment: @cool-RR works fine on Windows 7 x64 with FF5 as default browser.

Comment: It works and linux for me, and other people said it works on other platforms as well.

Just write it in webbrowser-y manner:

`file://C:/lol` with forward slashes. The same applies to linux: `file:///home/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS, you can use

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run["open", "your/path"])
```

Comment: was that so hard? =)  Thanks! Type-o in your example: missing open paren "(" to invoking subprocess.run

Answer (score 1):

One approach to something like this is maybe to prioritize readability, and prepare the code in such a manner that extracting abstractions is easy. You could take advantage of python higher order functions capabilities and go along these lines, throwing an exception if the proper function assignment cannot be made when a specific platform is not supported.

```
import subprocess
import sys


class UnsupportedPlatformException(Exception):
    pass


def _show_file_darwin():
    subprocess.check_call(["open", "--", path])

def _show_file_linux():
    subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", "--", path])

def _show_file_win32():
    subprocess.check_call(["explorer", "/select", path])

_show_file_func = {'darwin': _show_file_darwin, 
                   'linux': _show_file_linux,
                   'win32': _show_file_win32}

try:
    show_file = _show_file_func[sys.platform]
except KeyError:
    raise UnsupportedPlatformException


# then call show_file() as usual
```