# Most correct way to define a function with variations for platforms

Tags: python, python-3.x, correctness

Today I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631329/2512078), which defines a function *after* determining the system platform.

I had always assumed (or rather, never really considered otherwise) that the conditional for determining correct behavior for cross-platform functions should be placed *inside* the definition.

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def show_file(path):
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        subprocess.check_call(["open", "--", path])
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", "--", path])
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        subprocess.check_call(["explorer", "/select", path])
```

I am curious, is it more efficient to do it the way **@Dietrich Epp** has?

```py
if sys.platform == "darwin":
    def show_file(path):
        subprocess.check_call(["open", "--", path])
elif sys.platform == "linux":
    def show_file(path):
        subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", "--", path])
elif sys.platform == "win32":
    def show_file(path):
        subprocess.check_call(["explorer", "/select", path])
```

I have no idea if either of the above snippets work, but that isn't really part of the question regardless.

Comment: Voting to close my own question, as the accepted answer (and comments of others) suggest that this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One consequence of putting the `show_file()` function definition within the conditional is that trying to use this function on an unsupported platform will raise a `NameError`. Putting the conditionals inside the `show_file` function will cause it to silently fail unless you also include a `raise` in the final `else` block.

Up to you which is better. Personally I'd prefer a clear error on an unsupported platform, but I think for clarity this is probably best handled as a final `else` condition so the cause of the exception is very clear.

Efficiency between the two cases is negligible. I would be much more concerned with code readability and handling of exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The first version performs the platform check every time `show_file` is called; the second doesn't.  It probably doesn't make it slower enough to matter, though.

Comment: You are only telling me what I already know, I was asking "efficiency" versus "correctness". I know how it works, but which would you choose?

Comment: Then you shouldn't have asked "is it more efficient ".  And while I'm flattered you would care about my opinion, that's all it would be.

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" probably depends on your priorities.

One approach to something like this is maybe to prioritize readability, and prepare the code to extract abstractions. It could be along these lines, throwing an exception if the proper function assignment cannot be made because the platform is not supported.

```
import subprocess
import sys


class UnsupportedPlatformException(Exception):
    pass


def _show_file_darwin():
    subprocess.check_call(["open", "--", path])

def _show_file_linux():
    subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", "--", path])

def _show_file_win32():
    subprocess.check_call(["explorer", "/select", path])

_show_file_func = {'darwin': _show_file_darwin, 
                   'linux': _show_file_linux,
                   'win32': _show_file_win32}

try:
    show_file = _show_file_func[sys.platform]
except KeyError:
    raise UnsupportedPlatformException


# then call show_file() as usual
```