# open file in finder or explorer on linux or unix

Tags: python

I don't have any Mac OSx or Linux machine, but I want to implement the functionality like opening an explorer from a selected file path.

for example

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('explorer "E://temp//"')
```

the above code opens windows explorer for a specified path, how to do it for Mac or Linux ?

Comment: different linux distros are going to have different GUI file managers

Comment: this is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520493/python-show-in-finder

Comment: @MattiLyra -- Not quite.  That was just looking for `OS-X`.  This is more general

Comment: `gnome-open path` works if you're using the gnome desktop, but I don't know about other desktop environments...  `open path` works on OS-X.

Comment: in the link by Matti: on Mac Ned Deily has specfied a variable file_to_show that probably locates file after opening the finder is it doable in windows, which until now i didnt thought of, I have to say thanks to Matti for sharing link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) on linux and `open` on OS-X.

e.g.

```
subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open','/home/me/otherdir'])
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen(['open','/home/me/otherdir'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [desktop package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/desktop) (in particular its `open` function) to take care of the OS-specific details. It should work on Linux, Windows and OS X.

If you want to do this on your own, instead, you can:

- launch `xdg-open` on Linux;
- launch `open` on OS X;
- use `os.startfile` on Windows.